# How to stop VScode creating a symlink instead of a file

Tags: visual-studio-code, symlink

I have tried to google, this can't find anything or on here so suspect i'm being a noob, so perhaps someone can educate me.

I am copying a file from one directory within by repo in VScode to another. It is a MAKEFILE (which i'm not that familiar with anyway).

[image: File i wish to copy...]

I then select copy...

[image: copy file...]

And then i select a sub directory within same directory so i can paste

[image: Paste file to sub directory...]

Once i complete this, rather than the file being copied, it creates a syslink to the file which isn't what i want as i now need to modify the file...

[image: File is now a symlink :(]

Even if i create the file as a new file, this will still display as a symlink.

Am i doing something stupid here?

I have created the file through the command line but the file still shows as a symlink.

Driving me crazy, please help!

thanks :)

Comment: Is this a duplicate of ["Copy and paste file creates symbolic link? How to make it create a file instead?"](/q/69544888)?

Comment: Hi @rainbow.gekota yes it appears to be the same issue. I cant see a solution for this on this post either though :(

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here, just complete these steps:

1. Open VSCode and press Command+Shift+p
2. Type Uninstall and select option "Uninstall code command from PATH"
3. Input admin password and then close VSCode once it confirms its been removed
4. Close VScode application
5. Re-open VScode and press Command+Shift+p
6. Type "Install code command to PATH"
7. Input admin password

Try now and this should work.

I found if i didnt close VScode after removing/adding command to PATH, the setting was lost.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting. How did you come to this answer? Do you know why works to solve the problem? (thanks btw for sharing your finding!)